# CSS elements & positioning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position some elements properly but they seem to clip/interfere with each other and I am not sure how to solve the issue.

I would like a fixed positioned header at the top & bottom with a center element that does not clip with them. Inside of the center I would like a left and right sidebar which also doesnt clip with the center.

> Positioning & Size should not be absolute.
>
> Top / Bottom act as Header/Footer only these are supposed to be fixed.
>
> With this I mean that if I change my browsers width for example the content should 'resize'

Any idea or hint on how to achieve this?

```
|--------------------------------|
|       Top (fixed header)       |
|--------------------------------|
|------|  Center/content  |------|
|------|                  |------|
|------|         ^        |------|
|------|         |        |------|
| Left |   <--stretch-->  | Right|
|------|         |        |------|
|------|         v        |------|
|------|                  |------|
|--------------------------------|
|      Bottom(fixed footer)      |
|--------------------------------|
```

This is what I currently have, header & footer are positioned corretly but they clash with my other elements...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  float: bottom;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #aaa;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
}

.middle {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
}

.right {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Titel</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="header">
      <p>test2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="left">
        <p>test2</p>
      </div>
      <p>test2</p>
      <div class="right">
        <p>test2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    </page>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you show us your html?

Comment: If you're already using `position: fixed` why would you specifically want  "Positioning & Size should not be absolute"

Comment: Edited my post to be more specifc @WilliamIsted and added my HTML

Comment: I'd checkout this example, as I think it would be more straightforward than trying this layout with positioned elements https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/LmYay/ - Flexbox is designed for this style of layout

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle it really gets close to what I am trying to achieve but I would like the Scrollbar given by the Browser with the Header & Footer staying in position when scrolling and just the Center content moving hence why I used fixed for them.

Comment: Do you want to keep header position fixed ?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/RRakeshraj/dk4mezgb/1/

Comment: If the header / footer heights are not fixed you will need javascript to manage this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the height of your left and right bar to 100% of screen and I haven't seen this in your code.
Second because you are using **fixed position** for headers and footers but not for your **left and right bar** so the problem of interference of div is common.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
}

.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: Red;
    float: left;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  float: bottom;
  bottom: 0;
  background: Red;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.middle {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: Blue;
}

.right {
    position: fixed;
  width: 10%;
    height: 100vh;
  background: #bbb;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Titel</title>
    
<style type="text/css">
    
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="header">
      <p>test2</p>
      </div>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="left">
        <p>Left</p>
      </div>
      <p>test2</p>
      <div class="right">
        <p>test2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the left and right bar not to be fixed and now it works!
Do you know why my question shows -1? I am new to this Forum!

Comment: Yes may be because this type of question has already been asked somewhere on stackoverflow(not exactly same but related 80% related)

Answer (score 0):

I think you skiped something in your html file. You probably should place your middle div there.

If you want the top and the bottom bars to be fixed and the rest to be moving with the scrollbar, you should do the following:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <p>header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="left">
            <p>left</p>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <p>middle</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added a border for the top and the bottom panels so you can see what area they cover and what behind them is.

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    /*background: #ddd;*/
    border: 1px dashed #000;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    /*float: bottom;*/
    bottom: 0;
    /*background: #aaa;*/
    border: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

And your left, right and middle sections should be inline-blocks, I believe:

```
.left {
    width: 20%;
    /*height: 100;*/
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc;
}

.middle {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ddd;
}

.right {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    background: #bbb;
}
```

You may want to add some padding at the top of your center area, so that the top bar does not cover the center panel:

```
.center
{
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[Demo] https://jsfiddle.net/RRakeshraj/dk4mezgb/1/

**CODE**

```
<style>
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    text-align:center;
}
.header-wrap{
        height:55px;
        background:gray;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
}
.body-wrapper{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 55px auto;
    min-height: 800px;
    background:#eee;
}
.left-panel,.right-panel{
    min-height:557px;
    background: rgba(104, 241, 104, 0.68);
    width:15%;
    position:fixed;
}
.left-panel{
    top:55px;
    left:0;
}
.right-panel{
    top:55px;
    right:0;
}
.footer-wrap{
        height:50px;
        background:gray;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="header-wrap">
            <h3><!--Header--></h3>
        </div>
                <div class="left-panel"><h4><!--Left Panel--></h4></div>
                        <div class="body-wrapper">
                            <div class="content-panel"><h1><!--Content--></h1></div>
                        </div>
                <div class="right-panel"><h4><!--Right panel--></h4></div>
        <div class="footer-wrap">
            <h3><!--Footer--></h3>
        </div>
</div>
```